# linq async call to map to one object 2 tables with a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I know the title may sound awful, but is the best I could come up with. (Also my first question on stack:P)

I have reversed engineered a database and I have some classes looking like this:

```
public class Orders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    ...
    public Locations Location { get; set; }
    public Users User { get; set; }
}
public class Locations 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I also have 2 SQL tables "orders" and "locations" with a foreign key "LocationId"

If I am trying to do a select using LINQ like this:

```
var ordersResult = await _context.Orders.Where(o => <some condition>).ToListAsync();
```

Then it will fill my object with all the properties, excepting the Location object property which will be null. This makes sense, as I have made no join or anything like that.

I have no idea how do I have to writhe the LINQ statement so it will fill the entire object in only one async call without making multiple calls to the database.

I have also tried doing this:

```
var ordersResult = await _context.Orders.Join(_context.Locations,
                orders => orders.LocationId,
                locations=> locations.Id,
                (orders, locations) => new { Orders = orders, Locations = locations })
            .Where(orders_users => <some condition>)
            .Select(o => o.Orders)
            .ToListAsync();
```

but this still gives me a null for the Locations property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use include

```
await _context.Orders.Include("Location").Where(o => <some condition>).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks a lot! It works now (at least when debugging), but the API times out. It does the same thing when I am trying to do 2 async calls to the DB in the same method. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: Time out meaning you get a time out exception on database? Or is it that you get 0 results? If you get 0 results make sure your using await in front of any function that is async (not just db ToListAsync())

Comment: I am using Postman and I get this: "Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:55520/api/Orders/....."  If I take the include out it works perfectly.

Comment: And fiddler sais this: " [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 1,079 bytes." It is a 504 but I'm not sure how to sort it out.

Comment: Is this db call directly in your controller or in a manager/repo class?

Comment: It is inside an async method directly in the controller.

Comment: did you put await in front of that method call?

Comment: Yes, I did : var ordersResult = await _context.Orders.Include("Location").Where(o => o.....

Comment: Ok not sure, you would need to post your full controller code. It's not the Include that is causing the issue, unless you have millions of records in your db.

Comment: I have only 3 records for now. https://pastebin.com/db4UknZg Here is the controller code. the method is called: **"GetIncompleteOrdersOfUserAndDepartment"**

Comment: I have hosted it in Azure now and I am getting an OK back, but the JSON suddenly finishes somewhere in the middle after 695 characters.

Comment: Sorted! I had to set the **options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling** to **Ignore** in the  ConfigureServices method.

Comment: Ah that's right, infinite loop if your Locations have an order property.